# List all installed application and put them in a spinner

Tags: java, android

I want to do a small app that put all installed applications into a spinner and then gives you the option too choose one too get the `UID`. Unfortunately, I can't find any guide about how to populate the spinner with all installed applications (as you see the code is missing the `spinner`)

```
enter code here

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static String TAG="activity";
private Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    additemtospinner();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
 }

public void additemtospinner()
{
            spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
            int app_pos, long app_id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int UID;
            String selectapp=parent.getItemAtPosition(app_pos).toString();
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
          List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(selectapp)){
            UID = packageInfo.uid;
            break; 
        }

    }

}
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) a full tutorial to populate a spinner.

You can't add at the spinner an `ApplicationInfo`, you need to use an adpater for this. But the tutorial can explain this better than me ;).

For example with an `ArrayAdpater`. You need to create a `List<String>`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
```

After you need to create an `ArrayAdpater` with this list.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Finaly add the adapter to the `Spinner` and it will be populated.

```
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**EDIT**

You code isn't correct you create a list but empty.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

If your list is empty your spinner too :)

Try something like that :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    list.add(packageInfo.packageName)
}
```

Comment: If the tutorial website disappears, the link will be broken and the information will be lost. Could you be so kind to summarise the content of this tutorial and use the link as reference? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure :). I do it now.

Comment: I followed your advice and the tutorial but still cant get it to work :( I updated my code above

Comment: Thanks! :) I've added list.add("list"); and it prints whats within the "" but how do I get it show all my apps ? :( I've tested around abit now but still cant figure it out